# Convert lines into array and concatenate multiple lines into a multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a xml file with a 20  tags. I want to read these tags that contain numbers separated by a space between them (total 50 numbers each tag) and read them as an numpy array, concatenate them into a single array with 20 x 50 dimension. 
Sample file:

```
<xml>
<Purchase>
<Array> 1 2 3 4 5 6 </Array>
<Array> a b c d e f </Array>
<Array> 7 8 9 10 11 12</Array>
 ...
</Purchase>
</xml>
```

With code below, I can read individual lines as :

```
[(1 2 3 4 5 6)]
```

but I want an array that looks like this :

```
[(1 2 3 4 5 6), 
  (a b c d e f),
  (7 8 9 10 11 12),
  ...
  (   50th   row)]
```

I have read xml file using xml.etree.ElementTree, which works perfectly. I then tried to convert string to an array directly like this

```py
#Code above this works. tree is defined as tree = ET.fromstring(...)
segArray = tree.findall(".//Purchase/Array")
arrayList = np.array([])
arrayList.shape = (20,50)
#there are 50 items under that tag, so 1st item is 0th element in array 
for i in range (0, len(segArray) - 1):
 arrayNew = np.array([[i,segArray[i]]])
 arrayList = np.concatenate((arrayList,arrayNew))
print (arrayList)
```

Currently I am getting

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: Maybe try changing what axis you use on the concatenate call? Also, are you sure all entries in each `Array` tag have the same amount of elements?

Comment: With different axis, I still get same error. And yes, I am sure the tag contains 50 elements each.

Comment: is `segArray[i]` an array? In other words, is `segArray` a 2D array?

Comment: I would imagine you'd have to do more processing on `segArray[i]`, such as `segArray[i].text.split(" ")`. I don't think The ElementTree XML API automatically casts the Array tag into a real array

Comment: segArray is just a list with all of tags(rows) and its elements. segArray[i] is the i-th row in segArray. Like segArray[0] in the example above is 1 2 3 4 5 6.

Comment: Exactly, so when you say segArray[0] in the example above is 1 2 3 4 5 6, is it really already an array? Wouldn't it still be an xml Element object?

Comment: wow cant believe i was stuck at this, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I came to. Something to be wary of is trailing/leading/extra spaces in the Array tag. This solution will trim away those spaces by the list comprehension in the inner loop. Also, you can simplify working with shapes and all of that by simply casting to np array at the end of all the processing.

```
segArray = root.findall(".//Purchase/Array")
arrayList = []

for i in range (0, len(segArray) - 1):
    elems = segArray[i].text.split(" ")
    elems = [x for x in elems if x != '']
    arrayList.append(elems)

arrayList = np.array(arrayList)
```